# Data connection not displayed on page elements

Tags: community, data-loader

I am new to Salesforce community.I am trying to design a page using community for the customers and would like to display some custom object data on community pages. I am planning to use page data connection to retreive data. But when on site.com studio and when opening a page, I don't see option on Page element for Data connection.

I checked the permissions on setup and I do have previlage to site.com. Any idea why?

Comment: Any updates? Anyone know the answer for this?

Comment: I see that the issue is not just with data connection. I don't see the Form and Data elements at all on the site.com. I am using Napilli template for creating the community.